# pandas.DataFrame set all string values to nan

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that contain string, float and int types.

Is there a way to set all strings that cannot be converted to float to `NaN` ?

For example:

```py
    A  B   C      D
0   1  2   5      7
1   0  4 NaN     15
2   4  8   9     10
3  11  5   8      0
4  11  5   8  "wajdi"
```

to:

```py
    A  B   C      D
0   1  2   5      7
1   0  4 NaN     15
2   4  8   9     10
3  11  5   8      0
4  11  5   8    NaN
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` and set `errors='coerce'`

[pandas.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric)

`df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df.D, errors='coerce')`

Which will give you:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   5.0 7.0
1   0   4   NaN 15.0
2   4   8   9.0 10.0
3   11  5   8.0 0.0
4   11  5   8.0 NaN
```

**Deprecated solution** (pandas <= 0.20 only):

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

[pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html)

Here's the dev note in the `convert_objects` source code: `# TODO: Remove in 0.18 or 2017, which ever is sooner`. So don't make this a long term solution if you use it.

Comment: Nice answer! <padding>

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`.

```
In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 'NaN', 'bob', 3.2]})

In [31]: pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce')
Out[31]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    3.2
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Here is one way to apply it to all columns:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
```

(See comment by NinjaPuppy for a better way.)

Comment: Don't quite need to go with the looping over columns here: I believe you can use `df.apply(lambda L: pd.to_numeric(L, errors='coerce'))`...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way:

```
df['E'] = pd.to_numeric(df.D, errors='coerce')
```

And then you have:

```
    A  B    C      D     E
0   1  2  5.0      7   7.0
1   0  4  NaN     15  15.0
2   4  8  9.0     10  10.0
3  11  5  8.0      0   0.0
4  11  5  8.0  wajdi   NaN
```