# Find rows with non zero values in a subset of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datframe with 4 columns of strings and others as integers. Now I need to find out those rows of data where at least one of the column is a non-zero value (or > 0).

```
manwra,sahAyaH,T7,0,0,0,0,T
manwra, akriti,T5,0,0,1,0,K 
awma, prabrtih,B6, 0,1,1,0,S
```

My output should be

```
manwra, akriti,T5,0,0,1,0,K 
awma, prabrtih,B6, 0,1,1,0,S
```

I have tried the following to obtain the answer. The string values are in colums 0,1,2 and -1 (last column).

```
KT[KT.ix[:,3:-2] != 0]
```

What I am receiving as output is

```
NaN,NaNNaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,NaN,NaN
```

How to obtain the desired output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution which uses [select_dtypes()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method:

```
In [41]: df[(df.select_dtypes(include=['number']) != 0).any(1)]
Out[41]:
        0          1   2  3  4  5  6  7
1  manwra     akriti  T5  0  0  1  0  K
2    awma   prabrtih  B6  0  1  1  0  S
```

Explanation:

```
In [42]: df.select_dtypes(include=['number']) != 0
Out[42]:
       3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False
2  False   True   True  False

In [43]: (df.select_dtypes(include=['number']) != 0).any(1)
Out[43]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is a better answer

Answer (score 7):

assume your dataframe is `df`

```
df.loc[(df.loc[:, df.dtypes != object] != 0).any(1)]
```

[image]

Comment: @piRSqaured can a derivative of this be used for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184442/pandas-dataframe-set-all-string-values-to-nan/39184505#comment65710713_39184505 ... I got df.ix[:, df.dtypes == object ] ... couldnt apply back to DF....

Comment: @Merlin  TL;DR I don't think so at least not directly.  The core issue of the linked question is making an attempt to convert strings to numeric.  I was explicitly trusting that dtypes are accurate and have no interest in converting them.  If you applied this to the linked question, you'd miss the point of converting the string `"2.0"` to the float `2.0`.

Comment: Thanks, ok, was looking for replacement for convert_objects ( convert_numeric = True )

Comment: @Merlin what about `pd.to_numeric(df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].stack(), 'coerce').unstack()`

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
 #your's    
 KT[KT.ix[:,3:-2] != 0]

 #works 
 KT[(KT.ix[:,3:6] > 0).any(1)]

        0         1   2  3  4  5  6   7
1  manwra    akriti  T5  0  0  1  0  K 
2    awma  prabrtih  B6  0  1  1  0  S

 #key diff
 (KT.ix[:,3:6] > 0)
       3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False
2  False   True   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative solution

An **alternative** solution, which could be useful in *certain* situations. For example when plotting something and you do not want to create new copies of DataFrames just to filter out some rows and plot it. An added bonus is that the column dtypes in this solution are not limited to numbers, wherever you can do a comparison you can just add it to the eval call.

Guided answer from the start, first to read the data I use the `pandas.read_clipboard()` function.

```
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7
manwra sahAyaH T7 0 0 0 0 T
manwra akriti T5 0 0 1 0 K 
awma prabrtih B6 0 1 1 0 S
```

I added column names c0-c7 here. Just select this table and copy Ctrl+C it to the clipboard.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

and then by chaining an `.eval()` with a `.query()` on the DataFrame

```
df.eval("all_zero = (c3==0)&(c4==0)&(c5==0)&(c6==0)").query("all_zero==False")
```

we get the desired results.

|  | c0 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | all_zero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | manwra | akriti | T5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | K | False |
| 2 | awma | prabrtih | B6 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | S | False |

In the eval call we are just doing comparisons on the columns we want to be zero, if they are all zero the `&` sign will combine them to True (1) in column `all_zero`, then we can query the results and say we only want rows where this new column is False (we could as well say `all_zero!=True`, or changed the comparison in the eval call).

If you do not want the `all_zero` column just drop that as well

```
df.eval("all_zero = (c3==0)&(c4==0)&(c5==0)&(c6==0)").query("all_zero==False").drop('all_zero',axis=1)
```

|  | c0 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | manwra | akriti | T5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | K |
| 2 | awma | prabrtih | B6 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | S |

### Timings / Speed comparison

Comparing the speed of the solutions on a bigger DataFrame of same layout we see that my solution is slower (as expected), but it has some added benefits in terms of filtering more broadly. To compare timings I replicated the DataFrame so that it contains 30 000 rows instead

```
df = df.append([df]*(10000-1),ignore_index=True)
```

and then ran the different solutions on it and timed it.

[image: Quick timing comparison for the different solutions]

I will leave my solution here for reference!